# Creating a PDF and moving it to a directory?

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I am using PDFMake to create a PDF file, the body of which is dynamic. When I create the PDF it downloads to my downloads folder.

I would love for the PDF to be able to save to a directory of my choice. I have looked through the PDFMake docs and all I can see is that it gives you the option to give it a custom name. Does anyone know how I can make this happen. I don't want to just retrieve it from the folder it's in because it could possibly be in a different folder depending on the user.

Below is the code where I create the PDF:

```
function createPDF() {

    let body = tinymce.get('elm1').getContent();

    let docDefinition = {
      content: body
    };

    console.log(body);

    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
  }
```

Comment: You can use "pdfmake" printer and "fs" to write on filesystem.

Comment: @GregorWedlich Not quite sure what you mean, do you have a link where you have seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');

let printer = new PdfPrinter();

let docDefinition = {
    content: .....
};

pdf = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('YOUR-PDFs/YOUR-PDF.pdf'));
pdf.end();
```

Comment: I cannot use `require` I'm doing this in vanilla JS

Comment: You cannot write to the filesystem with Vanilla JS. You must use NodeJS or similar.

Comment: Ahh sorry you want to offer a special path for download on client site?

Comment: Yes instead of it automatically going to my `Downloads` folder. I'd like it to go to a folder somewhere in the project directory

Comment: I think pdfmake cannot do this.

[link](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/methods/)

Comment: Yes unfortunately. I'll have to look for another json -> pdf tool. Thank you for your help anyway